# Chinese loanwords whose characters also carry the corresponding meaning

Tags: loanwords

A while ago, I recall coming across some Chinese loanwords that not only sounded like their foreign language (usually English) counterparts, but whose characters also carried roughly that same meaning.

Unfortunately, I can't remember the examples now, but I'm wondering if anyone knows if there is a term for this type of word?  Also, I would like to know what such examples of this phenomenon other people have encountered.

Comment: Recently there was a post regarding 宝贝. Other loan word I can think about is 拜拜.

Comment: 俱樂部 (club), 迷你裙 (mini-skirt)

Comment: 殺必死 from Japanese is a great one http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/60901/

Answer (score 2):

Here are some examples of those

- 基因 - gene
- 嬉皮士 - hippies
- 脱口秀 - talk show
- 霸凌 - bully
- 流明 - lumen
- 黑客 - hacker
- 对偶 - dual
- 蕾丝 - lace
- 费 - fee

And some others

- 席梦思 - Simmons
- 可口可乐 - Coca Cola
- 必应 - Bing
- 翡冷翠 - Firenze (Italy)
- 氕 - protium
- 氘 - deuterium
- 氚 - tritium

Comment: I think 基因 was the original one I was thinking of!

Answer (score -1):

The term for this kind of words is **外来词** or **外来语**.  E.g. 酷: cool; 巧克力: chocolate; etc.

You can have a search for 外来词 or 外来语 to get more. This is from [Baidu](https://m.baidu.com/from=1000953c/s?word=%E5%A4%96%E6%9D%A5%E8%AF%8D&sa=tb&ts=8567534&t_kt=0&ie=utf-8&rsv_t=1395FgZFvXQl0R2PbkOIK9d3nvcLm2sWxgGKobZndA%252F8w3gaW2C2RP9yIdh%252F2pY&rsv_pq=9020641192815823030&ss=&tj=1&rqlang=zh&oq=%E5%A4%96%E6%9D%A5%E8%AF%8D).